How to get uniform thickness at corners with the skin modifier
I'm having trouble getting uniform thickness at the corners of my 3D model using the skin modifier in Blender.
I've applied the skin modifier to my mesh, but the thickness at the corners is inconsistent and doesn't match the rest of the model.
Does anyone have any tips or techniques for ensuring uniform thickness at corners when using the skin modifier? Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!


Hello, I don't think that you can have a square corner with the Skin modifier
